# ¿Cómo alinear un botón junto a un input?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Necesitaba su ayuda, estoy usando bootstrap 4 y jQuery para añadir inputs a un formulario, eso se hace sin problemas, el "problema" es que el botón + o - que he colocado junto a cada input no se alinea con el input sino que parece estar un poco más abajo. ¿De qué forma podría alinear los botones junto al input?

[image: alinearse]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; 
    var addButton = $('#add_button');
    var wrapper = $('#field_wrapper'); 
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" class="form-control mr-2 mb-2" name="field_name[]" placeholder="Correo"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove_button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></a></div>';
    var x = 1; 
    $(addButton).click(function(){ 
        if(x < maxField){ 
            x++; 
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); 
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '#remove_button', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
        x--;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css"/>
<div class="form-inline">
  <div id="field_wrapper">
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2 mb-2" name="field_name[]" placeholder="Correo"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info" id="add_button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa flexbox, pero antes quita la clase `mb-2` del input.

```css
.my-class-form-control-group{
  display:flex;
  align-items:Center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css"/>
<div class="form-inline">
  <div id="field_wrapper">
    <div class="my-class-form-control-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" name="field_name[]" placeholder="Correo"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info" id="add_button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

a la clase `mb-2` del input.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono perfectamente. Saludos.